# What animal is this? Caution, GRAPHIC!

Tags: species-identification, zoology, herpetology

One of my friends stumbled upon this half part of an animal. It seems lizard-like...I don't think I've ever seen a lizard that large, though. We live in Greece. Can you figure it out? Close-up and a zoomed-out version with the pavement in it for scale included (length was ~10-15cm / 4-6 inches).

[image]

[image]

Comment: this is very likely some type of skink a type of lizard https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skink

Answer (score 4):

My guess is the [**ocellated skink**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chalcides_ocellatus) (*Chalcides ocellatus*).

[image]

<sup>Credit: Adel Ibrahim ; Source: [The Reptile database](https://reptile-database.reptarium.cz/species?genus=Chalcides&species=ocellatus)</sup>

The species is names for its black/white ocellated, or eye-like, patched scales, similar to the ones seen in you specimen. *C. ocellatus* also would match your size (15-30 cm) and your location (generalist, including rocky).

It is found throughout the Mediterranean including in Greece.

See other similar specimens from Greece [here](http://en.balcanica.info/2-4140) and [here](https://zooinstitutes.com/animals/eyed-skink-aquaworld-aquarium-12704.html)